# Javascript object with a hidden function?

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming

I want to create a variable such that `foo.properties` returns `{default:{x:undefined}}`. However, you may notice that the properties variable is not directly editable and thus `__defineGetter__` is used to make it readable, yet not writable.

The problem is that I also want properties to be part of the *getter* if you will and NOT part of the properties variable. Yet here when you type `foo.properties` in the console it returns `{default:{x:undefined},attr:function(){ [native code] }}`. How can i stop attr from being associated with the properties variable?

```
var foo = new (function(){
    var properties = {
        default:{
            x:undefined
        }
    };
    this.__defineGetter__('properties',(function(){return properties;}).bind(this));
    this.properties.attr = (function(attr,value){
        var attr = attr.split('.');
        var recursive = function(attr,output,value){
            if(attr.length>1){
                return recursive(attr.slice(1),output[attr[0]],value);
            }else{
                if(value!=undefined){output[attr[0]] = value;};
                return output[attr[0]];
            };
        };
        return recursive(attr,properties,value || undefined);
    }).bind(this)
});
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I think that when `this.properties.attr` is set the *getter* returns the variable `properties` in place of `this.properties`. Thus the `properties` is directly getting edited. Perhaps it is possible to make the returned value from the *getter* a seperate entity from the actual `properties` variable?

Comment: Perhaps you want to return a new object, a view on `properties`, from the getter?

Comment: I gave it a shot, but the problem persists. Nice idea though!

Comment: Where should `attr` be located if not on the `properties` object?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so let me get this straight. You have a getter that returns the variable in the foo's scope. And you want to add the `.attr` property to the returned value only, and not alter the variable within foo's scope?

If that is correct, then you should go about this slightly differently. You are correct that it is returning the value from the getter, which is the same as the variable.

So, in order to work around this, we first need to clone the variable, assign the `.attr` then return it.

This code will do the trick :

```
var foo = new (function(){
    var properties = {
        default:{
            x:undefined
        }
    };
    this.__defineGetter__('properties',(function(){
      var temp = clone(properties);
      temp.attr = (function(attr,value){
            var attr = attr.split('.');
            var recursive = function(attr,output,value){
                if(attr.length>1){
                    return recursive(attr.slice(1),output[attr[0]],value);
                }else{
                    if(value!=undefined){output[attr[0]] = value;};
                    return output[attr[0]];
                };
            };
            return recursive(attr,properties,value || undefined);
        }).bind(this)
      return temp;
    }).bind(this));

});

function clone(obj){
    if(obj == null || typeof(obj) != 'object')
        return obj;

    var temp = obj.constructor();

    for(var key in obj)
        temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);
    return temp;
}
```

Here is a demonstration [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crzyman/sWn2s/1/)

Hope that helped!